# Problema com deploy no Heroku

Tags: java, jsf, maven, heroku

Estou utilizando Maven, Java, JSF, Primefaces, Hibernate, MySQL, CDI  e Tomcat 8 na maquina local para criar a app. Agora estou tentando subir e estou tendo grande dificuldade em fazer o projeto subir no Heroku.

criei o Procfile.txt na raiz do projeto :

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar --port $PORT target/*.war
```

adicionei o maven plugin :

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <appName>lojapdv</appName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

criei o app, fiz o deploy indo no projeto, clicando com o direito e em maven-build, em goals coloquei :  heroku heroku:deploy-war e ele subiu tranquilamento para o heroku. Então fui acessar a pagina pelo link disponibilizado pelo heroku:  https://lojapdv.herokuapp.com/, porem estou recebendo um 404.

Também não consegui configurar o BD, no caso estou usando MYSQL e teria de migrar para o Postgre que é free, mas estou com bastante dificuldade...

Answer (score 1):

Olá. 
1 - O Procfile é sem extensão.
2 - Você pode rodar o heroku local antes de fazer o deploy. Usando o heroku cli
   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local
3 - Da uma olhada nesse exemplo que subi recentemente para o heroku: 
   https://github.com/CodeClubBrasil/gerador-certificados

Espero que ajude